# Preconfigured num_labels on PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm writing a program to tag medical entities. I'm using NER (token classification) and combining datasets to teach the program on a wider range of medical topics. While preprocessing the data, I have to combine the labels to a unified label list, however, when I remap the functions, it says that the number of labels (28) is greater than the configured 19. Everything online says change the num_labels in the model, but the problem is: I haven't loaded in the model yet, I'm only preprocessing

1. Here's the code snippet that is throwing the error:

```
# Original ID to label mapping for ncbi_disease
ncbi_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-Disease",
    2: "I-Disease",
}

# Original ID to label mapping for tner_bionlp2004
tner_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-DNA",
    2: "I-DNA",
    3: "B-protein",
    4: "I-protein",
    5: "B-cell_type",
    6: "I-cell_type",
    7: "B-cell_line",
    8: "I-cell_line",
    9: "B-RNA",
    10: "I-RNA",
}

#Original ID to label mapping for BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease
BC5CDR_CD_id2label = {
    0: 'O',
    1: 'B-Disease',
    2: 'I-Disease',
    3: 'B-Chemical',
    4: 'I-Chemical',
}

# Original ID to label mapping for tner_bionlp2004
EMBO_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-SMALL_MOLECULE",
    2: "I-SMALL_MOLECULE",
    3: "B-GENEPROD",
    4: "I-GENEPROD",
    5: "B-SUBCELLULAR",
    6: "I-SUBCELLULAR",
    7: "B-CELL_TYPE",
    8: "I-CELL_TYPE",
    9: "B-TISSUE",
    10: "I-TISSUE",
    11: "B-ORGANISM",
    12: "I-ORGANISM",
    13: "B-EXP_ASSAY",
    14: "I-EXP_ASSAY",
    15: "B-DISEASE", 
    16: "I-DISEASE",
    17: "B-CELL_LINE",
    18: "I-CELL_LINE",

}


#Theoretically, add new Original ID dictionaries of new datasets Here.

# New, Global ID to label mapping (ALL LOWERCASE)
global_id2label = {
    0: "o",
    1: "b-disease", #Used in Multiple Datasets
    2: "i-disease", #Used in Multiple Datasets
    3: "b-dna",
    4: "i-dna",
    5: "b-protein",
    6: "i-protein",
    7: "b-cell_type",
    8: "i-cell_type",
    9: "b-cell_line",
    10: "i-cell_line",
    11: "b-rna",
    12: "i-rna",
    13: "b-chemical",
    14: "i-chemical",
    15: "b-small_molecule",
    16: "i-small_molecule",
    17: "b-geneprod",
    18: "i-geneprod",
    19: "b-subcellular",
    20: "i-subcellular",
    21: "b-tissue",
    22: "i-tissue",
    23: "b-organism",
    24: "i-organism",
    25: "b-exp_assay",
    26: "i-exp_assay",
    27: "b-cell_line",
    28: "i-cell_line",
    # Add new mappings of other datasets here
}


# New, Global label to ID mapping. Note, each needs a unique ID. For example, B-Disease and I-Disease are used by multipe datasets, but you only need to put it in once here. It will be mapped correctly to each respective dataset
global_label2id = {
    "o": 0,
    "b-disease": 1, #Used in Multiple Datasets
    "i-disease": 2, #Used in Multiple Datasets
    "b-dna": 3,
    "i-dna": 4,
    "b-protein": 5,
    "i-protein": 6,
    "b-cell_type": 7,
    "i-cell_type": 8,
    "b-cell_line": 9,
    "i-cell_line": 10,
    "b-rna": 11,
    "i-rna": 12,
    "b-chemical": 13,
    "i-chemical": 14,
    "b-small_molecule": 15,
    "i-small_molecule": 16,
    "b-geneprod": 17,
    "i-geneprod": 18,
    "b-subcellular": 19,
    "i-subcellular": 20,
    "b-tissue": 21,
    "i-tissue": 22,
    "b-organism": 23,
    "i-organism": 24,
    "b-exp_assay": 25,
    "i-exp_assay": 26,
    "b-cell_line": 27,
    "i-cell_line": 28,
    # Add new mappings of other datasets here
}

global_num_labels = len(global_id2label + 1) 

# Map from original label to new label for ncbi_disease
ncbi_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[ncbi_id2label[key].lower()] for key in ncbi_id2label}

# Map from original label to new label for tner_bionlp2004
tner_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[tner_id2label[key].lower()] for key in tner_id2label}

# Map from original label to new label for tner_bionlp2004
BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[BC5CDR_CD_id2label[key].lower()] for key in BC5CDR_CD_id2label}

EMBO_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[EMBO_id2label[key].lower()] for key in EMBO_id2label}

#Add Function to map other datasets here


# Map the labels in the ncbi_disease dataset to the new labels. Note you have to turn the label ID's into their names before being used in the remapping function
def remap_ncbi_labels(example):
    # Initialize a new list to hold the combined labels
    new_labels = []

    # If the "tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([ncbi_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    # If the "ner_tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([ncbi_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    # If new_labels is empty, set it to None
    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    # Return the example with a new "labels" column
    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

# Map the labels in the tner_bionlp2004 dataset to the new labels
def remap_tner_labels(example):
    new_labels = []

    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([tner_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([tner_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None


    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

# Map the labels in the BC5CDR Chemical Disease dataset to the new labels
def remap_BC5CDR_CD_labels(example):
    # Initialize a new list to hold the combined labels
    new_labels = []

    # If the "tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    # If the "ner_tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    # If new_labels is empty, set it to None
    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    # Return the example with a new "labels" column
    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

def remap_EMBO_labels(example):
    new_labels = []

    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    if "labels" in example and example["labels"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["labels"]])

    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

#Add functions to map new datasets here


# Remap each dataset
remapped_ncbi_disease = ncbi_disease.map(remap_ncbi_labels)
remapped_tner_bionlp2004 = tner_bionlp2004.map(remap_tner_labels)
remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease.map(remap_BC5CDR_CD_labels)
remapped_EMBO = EMBO_Source_Data.map(remap_EMBO_labels)
# Add new datasets here...

# Now remove the unnecessary columns (You have to input each column manually though for each dataset). We do this because the length of the columns are now different, and we cant combine them anymore.
remapped_ncbi_disease = remapped_ncbi_disease.remove_columns(["ner_tags"])
remapped_tner_bionlp2004 = remapped_tner_bionlp2004.remove_columns(["tags"])
remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease.remove_columns(["ner_tags"])
# Do this for all your datasets...

# Combine datasets
combined_dataset_train = concatenate_datasets([
    remapped_ncbi_disease["train"],
    remapped_tner_bionlp2004["train"],
    remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["train"],
    remapped_EMBO["train"]
    # Add more datasets...
])

# Combine datasets
combined_dataset_test = concatenate_datasets([
    remapped_ncbi_disease["test"],
    remapped_tner_bionlp2004["test"],
    remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["test"],
    remapped_EMBO["test"]
    # Add more datasets...
])
```

2. And here's the full code for context and what's happening before that etc.:

```
## 1. Load Dataset
            1.1 Login to Huggingface
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login

notebook_login()
#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
            1.2 Load the Datasets
from datasets import load_dataset, concatenate_datasets

# Load Datasets
ncbi_disease = load_dataset("ncbi_disease") 
tner_bionlp2004 = load_dataset("tner/bionlp2004")
BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = load_dataset("ghadeermobasher/BC5CDR-Chemical-Disease")
EMBO_Source_Data = load_dataset("EMBO/SourceData")
#Add other datasets here
## 2. Dataset Information
            2.1 Information for ncbi_disease database

label_list_ncbi_disease = ncbi_disease["train"].features[f"ner_tags"].feature.names #You'll need to change the name of features to whatever the dataset has as labeled
print(ncbi_disease, label_list_ncbi_disease)
            2.2 Information for tner_bionlp2004 database
label_dict_tner_bionlp2004 = {
    "O": 0,
    "B-DNA": 1,
    "I-DNA": 2,
    "B-protein": 3,
    "I-protein": 4,
    "B-cell_type": 5,
    "I-cell_type": 6,
    "B-cell_line": 7,
    "I-cell_line": 8,
    "B-RNA": 9,
    "I-RNA": 10
}

print(tner_bionlp2004)
            2.3 Information from ghadeermobasher/BC5CDR-Chemical-Disease

label_list_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["train"].features[f"ner_tags"].feature.names #You'll need to change the name of features to whatever the dataset has as labeled
print(BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease, label_list_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease)
            2.4 Information from EMBO/SourceData

label_list_EMBO_Source_Data = EMBO_Source_Data["train"].features[f"labels"].feature.names #You'll need to change the name of features to whatever the dataset has as labeled
print(EMBO_Source_Data, label_list_EMBO_Source_Data)
## 3. Tokenize and Preprocess Datasets
            3.1 Load a tokenizer to preprocess the tokens field
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

# As you saw in the example tokens field above, it looks like the input has already been tokenized. But the input actually hasn’t been tokenized yet and you’ll need to set is_split_into_words=True to tokenize the words into subwords. For example:

example_ncbi_disease = ncbi_disease["train"][0]
example_tner_bionlp2004 = tner_bionlp2004["train"][0]
example_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["train"][0]
example_EMBO_Source_Data = EMBO_Source_Data["train"][0]#Add all of the datasets to get an example of each

tokenized_input_ncbi_disease = tokenizer(example_ncbi_disease["tokens"], is_split_into_words=True)
tokenized_input_tner_bionlp2004 = tokenizer(example_tner_bionlp2004["tokens"], is_split_into_words=True)
tokenized_input_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = tokenizer(example_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["tokens"], is_split_into_words=True)
tokenized_input_EMBO_Source_Data = tokenizer(example_EMBO_Source_Data["words"], is_split_into_words=True) #Note this ones a little different


tokens_ncbi_disease = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenized_input_ncbi_disease["input_ids"])
tokens_tner_bionlp2004 = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenized_input_tner_bionlp2004["input_ids"])
tokens_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenized_input_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["input_ids"])
tokens_EMBO_Source_Data = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenized_input_EMBO_Source_Data["input_ids"])


tokens_EMBO_Source_Data, tokens_ncbi_disease, tokens_tner_bionlp2004, tokens_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease, 
            3.2 get rid of special tokens, realign the tokens and labels, and truncate sequences to be no longer than DistilBERT’s maximum input length:
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples, token_column_names, label_column_names):
    # Determine the token and label column
    token_column = next((col for col in token_column_names if col in examples), None)
    label_column = next((col for col in label_column_names if col in examples), None)

    if token_column is None or label_column is None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid column names")

    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples[token_column], truncation=True, max_length=512, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[label_column]):  # Use the determined label column here
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)  # Map tokens to their respective word.
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:  # Set the special tokens to -100.
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:  # Only label the first token of a given word.
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            else:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs

# Define your column names
token_column_names = ["tokens", "words"] #Change these to the column names for the text
label_column_names = ["ner_tags", "tags", "labels"] ##Change these to the column names for the tags

# Bind the extra arguments
from functools import partial

tokenize_and_align_labels_with_names = partial(tokenize_and_align_labels, token_column_names=token_column_names, label_column_names=label_column_names)

tokenized_ncbi_disease = ncbi_disease.map(tokenize_and_align_labels_with_names, batched=True) 
tokenized_tner_bionlp2004 = tner_bionlp2004.map(tokenize_and_align_labels_with_names, batched=True) 
tokenized_input_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease.map(tokenize_and_align_labels_with_names, batched=True)
tokenized_input_EMBO_Source_Data = EMBO_Source_Data.map(tokenize_and_align_labels_with_names, batched=True)#The following lines map the names to the tokenized datasets. You'll need to add the other datasets as you add them

            3.3 Create a batch of examples using DataCollatorWithPadding. 
*It’s more efficient to dynamically pad the sentences to the longest length in a batch during collation, instead of padding the whole dataset to the max length*
from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification

data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer=tokenizer)
            3.4 Create a map of ids to labels: id2label/label2id

*Before you start training your model, create a map of the expected ids to their labels with id2label and label2id:
Note that this is the combined list that changes the datasets to have aligned labels*
# Original ID to label mapping for ncbi_disease
ncbi_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-Disease",
    2: "I-Disease",
}

# Original ID to label mapping for tner_bionlp2004
tner_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-DNA",
    2: "I-DNA",
    3: "B-protein",
    4: "I-protein",
    5: "B-cell_type",
    6: "I-cell_type",
    7: "B-cell_line",
    8: "I-cell_line",
    9: "B-RNA",
    10: "I-RNA",
}

#Original ID to label mapping for BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease
BC5CDR_CD_id2label = {
    0: 'O',
    1: 'B-Disease',
    2: 'I-Disease',
    3: 'B-Chemical',
    4: 'I-Chemical',
}

# Original ID to label mapping for tner_bionlp2004
EMBO_id2label = {
    0: "O",
    1: "B-SMALL_MOLECULE",
    2: "I-SMALL_MOLECULE",
    3: "B-GENEPROD",
    4: "I-GENEPROD",
    5: "B-SUBCELLULAR",
    6: "I-SUBCELLULAR",
    7: "B-CELL_TYPE",
    8: "I-CELL_TYPE",
    9: "B-TISSUE",
    10: "I-TISSUE",
    11: "B-ORGANISM",
    12: "I-ORGANISM",
    13: "B-EXP_ASSAY",
    14: "I-EXP_ASSAY",
    15: "B-DISEASE", 
    16: "I-DISEASE",
    17: "B-CELL_LINE",
    18: "I-CELL_LINE",

}


#Theoretically, add new Original ID dictionaries of new datasets Here.

# New, Global ID to label mapping (ALL LOWERCASE)
global_id2label = {
    0: "o",
    1: "b-disease", #Used in Multiple Datasets
    2: "i-disease", #Used in Multiple Datasets
    3: "b-dna",
    4: "i-dna",
    5: "b-protein",
    6: "i-protein",
    7: "b-cell_type",
    8: "i-cell_type",
    9: "b-cell_line",
    10: "i-cell_line",
    11: "b-rna",
    12: "i-rna",
    13: "b-chemical",
    14: "i-chemical",
    15: "b-small_molecule",
    16: "i-small_molecule",
    17: "b-geneprod",
    18: "i-geneprod",
    19: "b-subcellular",
    20: "i-subcellular",
    21: "b-tissue",
    22: "i-tissue",
    23: "b-organism",
    24: "i-organism",
    25: "b-exp_assay",
    26: "i-exp_assay",
    27: "b-cell_line",
    28: "i-cell_line",
    # Add new mappings of other datasets here
}


# New, Global label to ID mapping. Note, each needs a unique ID. For example, B-Disease and I-Disease are used by multipe datasets, but you only need to put it in once here. It will be mapped correctly to each respective dataset
global_label2id = {
    "o": 0,
    "b-disease": 1, #Used in Multiple Datasets
    "i-disease": 2, #Used in Multiple Datasets
    "b-dna": 3,
    "i-dna": 4,
    "b-protein": 5,
    "i-protein": 6,
    "b-cell_type": 7,
    "i-cell_type": 8,
    "b-cell_line": 9,
    "i-cell_line": 10,
    "b-rna": 11,
    "i-rna": 12,
    "b-chemical": 13,
    "i-chemical": 14,
    "b-small_molecule": 15,
    "i-small_molecule": 16,
    "b-geneprod": 17,
    "i-geneprod": 18,
    "b-subcellular": 19,
    "i-subcellular": 20,
    "b-tissue": 21,
    "i-tissue": 22,
    "b-organism": 23,
    "i-organism": 24,
    "b-exp_assay": 25,
    "i-exp_assay": 26,
    "b-cell_line": 27,
    "i-cell_line": 28,
    # Add new mappings of other datasets here
}

global_num_labels = len(global_id2label + 1) 

# Map from original label to new label for ncbi_disease
ncbi_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[ncbi_id2label[key].lower()] for key in ncbi_id2label}

# Map from original label to new label for tner_bionlp2004
tner_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[tner_id2label[key].lower()] for key in tner_id2label}

# Map from original label to new label for tner_bionlp2004
BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[BC5CDR_CD_id2label[key].lower()] for key in BC5CDR_CD_id2label}

EMBO_label2new_label = {key: global_label2id[EMBO_id2label[key].lower()] for key in EMBO_id2label}

#Add Function to map other datasets here


# Map the labels in the ncbi_disease dataset to the new labels. Note you have to turn the label ID's into their names before being used in the remapping function
def remap_ncbi_labels(example):
    # Initialize a new list to hold the combined labels
    new_labels = []

    # If the "tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([ncbi_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    # If the "ner_tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([ncbi_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    # If new_labels is empty, set it to None
    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    # Return the example with a new "labels" column
    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

# Map the labels in the tner_bionlp2004 dataset to the new labels
def remap_tner_labels(example):
    new_labels = []

    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([tner_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([tner_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None


    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

# Map the labels in the BC5CDR Chemical Disease dataset to the new labels
def remap_BC5CDR_CD_labels(example):
    # Initialize a new list to hold the combined labels
    new_labels = []

    # If the "tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    # If the "ner_tags" column exists and is not None, remap its labels
    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([BC5CDR_CD_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    # If new_labels is empty, set it to None
    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    # Return the example with a new "labels" column
    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

def remap_EMBO_labels(example):
    new_labels = []

    if "tags" in example and example["tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["tags"]])

    if "ner_tags" in example and example["ner_tags"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["ner_tags"]])

    if "labels" in example and example["labels"] is not None:
        new_labels.extend([EMBO_label2new_label[tag] for tag in example["labels"]])

    if not new_labels:
        new_labels = None

    return {**example, "labels": new_labels}

#Add functions to map new datasets here


# Remap each dataset
remapped_ncbi_disease = ncbi_disease.map(remap_ncbi_labels)
remapped_tner_bionlp2004 = tner_bionlp2004.map(remap_tner_labels)
remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease.map(remap_BC5CDR_CD_labels)
remapped_EMBO = EMBO_Source_Data.map(remap_EMBO_labels)
# Add new datasets here...

# Now remove the unnecessary columns (You have to input each column manually though for each dataset). We do this because the length of the columns are now different, and we cant combine them anymore.
remapped_ncbi_disease = remapped_ncbi_disease.remove_columns(["ner_tags"])
remapped_tner_bionlp2004 = remapped_tner_bionlp2004.remove_columns(["tags"])
remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease = remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease.remove_columns(["ner_tags"])
# Do this for all your datasets...

# Combine datasets
combined_dataset_train = concatenate_datasets([
    remapped_ncbi_disease["train"],
    remapped_tner_bionlp2004["train"],
    remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["train"],
    remapped_EMBO["train"]
    # Add more datasets...
])

# Combine datasets
combined_dataset_test = concatenate_datasets([
    remapped_ncbi_disease["test"],
    remapped_tner_bionlp2004["test"],
    remapped_BC5CDR_Chemical_Disease["test"],
    remapped_EMBO["test"]
    # Add more datasets...
])

This just pulls the unique labels (with their ID's) to check that the combined dataset was remapped correctly
def print_unique_labels(dataset):
    unique_labels = set()
    for example in dataset:
        if "labels" in example and example["labels"] is not None:
            for label in example["labels"]:
                if label is not None:
                    unique_labels.add(label)
                else:
                    print("Found None in labels:", example)
        else:
            print("Found example with no labels:", example)
    
    # Create a list of tuples (label_id, label_name)
    labels_id_name = [(label, global_id2label.get(label, "Unknown")) for label in unique_labels]
    # Sort the list by label_id
    labels_id_name.sort()

    print("ID and Label Name:")

    for label_id, label_name in labels_id_name:
        print(f"{label_id}:{label_name}")

print_unique_labels(combined_dataset_train)

print_unique_labels(combined_dataset_test)
Same thing as before, but with our new, combined dataset, for both the train and test set
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

examples = combined_dataset_train["tokens"]
tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples, is_split_into_words=True)

tokens = [tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids) for input_ids in tokenized_inputs["input_ids"]]

tokens

Here is how you can create a function to get rid of special tokens, realign the tokens and labels, and truncate sequences to be no longer than DistilBERT’s maximum input length.
Remember to do it for both the train and test function
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], truncation=True, max_length=128, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[f"labels"]):
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)  # Map tokens to their respective word.
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:  # Set the special tokens to -100.
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:  # Only label the first token of a given word.
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            else:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs

#To apply the preprocessing function over the entire dataset, use  Datasets map function. You can speed up the map function by setting batched=True to process multiple elements of the dataset at once:
tokenized_combined_dataset_train = combined_dataset_train.map(tokenize_and_align_labels, batched=True)
Same thing for the test set. Tokenize the Test set
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

examples = combined_dataset_test["tokens"]
tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples, is_split_into_words=True)

tokens = [tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids) for input_ids in tokenized_inputs["input_ids"]]

tokens

And Align the Test Set
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], truncation=True, max_length=128, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[f"labels"]):
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)  # Map tokens to their respective word.
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:  # Set the special tokens to -100.
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:  # Only label the first token of a given word.
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            else:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs

tokenized_combined_dataset_test = combined_dataset_test.map(tokenize_and_align_labels, batched=True)
from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification

data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer=tokenizer)
import evaluate

seqeval = evaluate.load("seqeval")
import numpy as np

# Global label list that includes all possible labels across datasets
global_label_list = [
    "O",
    "B-Disease",
    "I-Disease",
    "B-DNA",
    "I-DNA",
    "B-protein",
    "I-protein",
    "B-cell_type",
    "I-cell_type",
    "B-cell_line",
    "I-cell_line",
    "B-RNA",
    "I-RNA",
    "B-Chemical",
    "I-Chemical",
    #Add other Labels here from global label list
]

def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    true_predictions = [
        [global_label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [global_label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]

    results = seqeval.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }

#Then trainer arguments
```